# move MenuStrip item text into resource file

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I am using .NET WinForms (C#) I have a form with a menustrip control in it, I added menu items in the designer and assigned test to them, now I want to move this text into a resource file. how do I do that ?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this for localization reasons? if so @Anurag 's answer would probably work for you just add to the Text Property of your existing `MenuItems` instead of creating new. Take a look at this link on the [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx) and this link on creating [Resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Resourcemanager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk.aspx) to set the string of the MenuItem.

So you can have something like:

```
MenuItem topLevel = mainMenu.MenuItems.Add("&XXX");
MenuItem first = new MenuItem();
first.Text = [Text from ResourceManager]
topLevel.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("&New"));
```

Comment: That doesnt help me, since my menu is already created throughout our application, I am trying to minimize my efforts in creating menus on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Project > Add New Item > Resourece File
2. Add string in resource...
3. Open your FormDesigner.cs, find and replace Text to
   this.stripItem.Text = global::your_app_namespace.resource_name.resource_value;